# php postgres pdo fetch and select query

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am new with pdo and php so please bear with me.

What I wanted is to create secure connection with db and get data. But as I checked there is not even db connection. When I inspect element I found this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

I checked it and I think I know what does it mean, but I could not fix it

here my codes,

```
global $dbname = $_GET['dbname'];
global $table = $_GET['table'];
global $yerId= $_GET['gid'];

try {
    $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=localhost", "postgres", "postgres" );
    $sql = $db->query ("SELECT km, turu, hat_kesimi, ili, ilcesi, mahadi FROM $table WHERE gid = $yerId ");
    while($result = $sql-> fetch(PDO_FETCH_ASSOC)  ) {
        printf ('<table><thead><tr><th  colspan="4" align="left" >TCDD 3.BOLGE MUDURLUGU <img src="tcdd.png" align="right" width="92px" /></th></tr><tr><th  colspan="4">Hemzemin Gecitler ve Ozellikeri</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th>Kilometre</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th>Turu</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th>Hat Kesimi</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th>Sehir</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th>Ilce</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th>Mahalle</th><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr><tr><th colspan="4" > copyright © all rights reserved by Piri Reis Bilisim  </th></tr></tbody></table>', $result["km"],$result["turu"], $result["hat_kesimi"], $result["ili"], $result["ilcesi"],$result["mahadi"]);        
    }

    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: why are you getting your database credentials using $_GET 

Are your appending all of your credentials to your url .. it is not a good practice plus a security breach too

Comment: If you encounter 500 errors check the error log of your webserver. There usually is a clear error message detailing what's wrong.

Comment: first gerald, now I am not getting that error but what i want does not happen, codes does work with no error

second  @justrohu , i have to use get method

Comment: I would suggest to hash the $_GET values by using base64_encode just to be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code through `PHP -l` I get the following errormessage:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in test.php on line 2
>   Errors parsing test.php

Just remove the `global` keyword here, it's wrong:

```
$dbname = $_GET['dbname'];
$table = $_GET['table'];
$yerId= $_GET['gid'];
```

Comment: thank you a lot, at least the css and html loaded when I removed global. but the data which will come from databese cannot be reached